# How can you pass a list to CMake using -D?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to call add_test(), like so:

```
add_test(NAME ${TEST_NAME} COMMAND cmake
  -DTEST_PROG:FILEPATH=${TEST_EXECUTABLE} 
 ...
  -DTEST_EXEC_DIRS:PATH=${TEST_EXEC_DIRS}
  -P SciTextCompare.cmake
)
```

${TEST_EXEC_DIRS} is a CMake list, and when I execute the above code, the resulting line in CTestTestfile.cmake only contains the first item in the list so, that I end up with the following arguments to cmake:

```
"cmake" "-DTEST_PROG:FILEPATH=C:/path/to/my/executable" ... "-DTEST_EXEC_DIRS:PATH=C:/first/dir/in/list" "-P" "SciTextCompare.cmake"
```

How can I pass in a list and have it invoke cmake like so:

```
"cmake" "-DTEST_PROG:FILEPATH=C:/path/to/my/executable" ... "-DTEST_EXEC_DIRS:PATH=C:/first/dir/in/list;C:/second/dir/in/list" "-P" "SciTextCompare.cmake"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using CMake version 2.8.11 or later you can use the [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#escaped-characters) `$<SEMICOLON>` to prevent the list expansion on an argument with ';':

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
...
string (REPLACE ";" "$<SEMICOLON>" GENERATOR_TEST_EXEC_DIRS "${TEST_EXEC_DIRS}")
add_test(NAME ${TEST_NAME} COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
  -DTEST_PROG:FILEPATH=${TEST_EXECUTABLE} 
 ...
  -DTEST_EXEC_DIRS:PATH=${GENERATOR_TEST_EXEC_DIRS}
  -P SciTextCompare.cmake
)
```

Comment: Yes - a better answer than mine :-)  I'll leave mine up for those stuck with version < 2.8.11, but this should be marked as the correct answer I think.

Answer (score 2):

There possibly is (or will be) a better way than this, but you can use a workaround whereby you temporarily replace the CMake list separator (i.e. `;`) with a different character.

I tend to use an ASCII control character to avoid accidentally substituting the `;`s with a character which is used elsewhere in the variable (which would cause an error when swapping the replacement separators back out).

So, in your CMakeLists.txt you could do:

```
string(ASCII 2 WORKAROUND_SEPARATOR)

string(REPLACE ";" ${WORKAROUND_SEPARATOR}
       WORKAROUND_TEST_EXEC_DIRS "${TEST_EXEC_DIRS}")

add_test(NAME ${TEST_NAME} COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
  -DTEST_PROG:FILEPATH=${TEST_EXECUTABLE}
  ...
  -DWORKAROUND_TEST_EXEC_DIRS:PATH=${WORKAROUND_TEST_EXEC_DIRS}
  -DWORKAROUND_SEPARATOR:INTERNAL=${WORKAROUND_SEPARATOR}
  -P SciTextCompare.cmake
)
```

Then in SciTextCompare.cmake, you just need to swap the normal separators back in:

```
string(REPLACE ${WORKAROUND_SEPARATOR} ";"
       TEST_EXEC_DIRS "${WORKAROUND_TEST_EXEC_DIRS}")
```

A minor point - you should probably prefer `${CMAKE_COMMAND}` rather than `cmake` in case the CMake executable isn't in the system path.

Comment: Thanks, Fraser! This is essentially what I ended up doing, although I used a '@' as a workaround separator. Your solution of using a control character is better. I was just hoping there was a way to do it directly. Also, I am actually using ${CMAKE_COMMAND}, I was just trying to simplify the code snippet, but that was one place I should've left it alone.